# .htaccess not working for a specific case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing a strange issue while working with .htaccess file.

Here is my file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^$ ./web/view/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ./web/view/?module=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2&id2=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2&id2=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2

ErrorDocument 404 err.php

</IfModule>
```

Now in the last rule, if I add `[a-z]` along with `[0-9]`, I am getting a 500 error. E.g., the below line will give me 500 error:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2
```

However, if I use `A-Z`, it is working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2
```

Even `[NC]` is also giving me same error.

Can you help me to identify and correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Now in the last rule, if I add `[a-z]` along with `[0-9]`, I am getting a 500 error. E.g., the below line will give me 500 error:

The reason is because the rewrite engine is going into an infinite loop:

1. request URI looks like `/something/id/` (note the trailing slash)
2. it matches the rule: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2`
3. URI gets rewritten to `/web/view/?module=something&id=id`
4. new URI is put back into the rewrite engine, new URI = `/web/view/`
5. URI matches the (same) rule: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2`
6. URI gets rewritten to `/web/view/?module=web&id=view`
7. repeat from step 4

You need to add a condition to prevent it from looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/web/view
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to add a [L] at the end of each rewrite line, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ./web/view/?module=$1 [L]
```

This works just fine since your rewrites are independent of each other.

The second step is to consolidate each group of RewriteRule directives where the forward slash (/) is optional, so instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ./web/view/?module=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ ./web/view/?module=$1
```

It is just as safe to say:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ ./web/view/?module=$1
```

The question mark (?) means 0 or 1 but not more than the preceding character, group or expression.

Lastly you may consider optimizing the group of RewriteRule directives:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^$ ./web/view/ [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?((([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?)?(([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?)?)?$ ./web/view/?module=$1&id1=$4&id2=$6 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 err.php

</IfModule>
```

And as bonus information, it may be worth your while to use the [QSA (query string append) flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), for example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ ./web/view/ [L,QSA]
```

You may also consider using [gskinner's RegExr tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to help you create, test or troubleshoot your regular expressions.

Lasty, in your .htaccess file, depending on how the AllowOverrides directive is defined, you *may* be able to turn on [mod_rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog):

```
RewriteLog "/path/to/your/home/dir/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 4
```

However, depending on your apache server version or configuration, you may be required to use the [per-module logging configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) since RewriteLog/Level is deprecated:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace4
```

As a disclaimer, this level of logging will slow down your webserver, so do not enable it for too long nor on a production environment.